# Check if a particular list in a "list of lists" is full or not in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm playing Tic Tac Toe and the columns are represented by lists, 
so classic 3x3 Tic Tac full of alternating X and O, from bottom to up, for three columns, would be [X,O,X][X,O,X][X,O,X]. Empty would be represented by Empty I guess (is that a good idea or bad idea)

How would I check if a selected column X, is full?

I want to have a function called Checker :: board -> Int -> Bool

Not really sure where to begin on defining the function Checker.

Edit: Clarifications

1) The board (like any real life game of Tic Tac Toe) will start off obviously as
 [empty,empty,empty][empty,empty,empty][empty,empty,empty]

or it will start off as the empty list and a function needs to transform it to 
[empty,empty,empty][empty,empty,empty][empty,empty,empty]

2) I want to check if the column is full, so to error check. I do not want players to add X's or O's to full columns. Columns could be filled up with any combination of X's and O's, just like mid way in a real life game of Tic-Tac-Toe.

3) The board is a list of lists. Columns by human interpretation are merely lists

So in a tic tac toe board that is ALL X's EXCEPT the middle being an O, is 
[X,X,X][X.O,X][X,X,X]

Comment: I am confused, 1) What do you mean by "Empty". 2) you wanna check if the column is full? of what? 3) the board is supposed to be a list of rows or columns?

Comment: 1) The board (like any real life game of Tic Tac Toe) will start off obviously as
 [empty,empty,empty][empty,empty,empty][empty,empty,empty]

or it will start off as the empty list and a function needs to transform it to 
[empty,empty,empty][empty,empty,empty][empty,empty,empty]

2) I want to check if the column is full, so to error check.

3) The board is a list of lists. Columns by human interpretation are merely lists

So in a tic tac toe board that is ALL X's EXCEPT the middle being an O, is 
[X,X,X][X.O,X][X,X,X]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a given (1-dimensional) list is all `X` with

```
all (== X) list
```

(As long as your data type has an `Eq` instance, which you can give it with e.g.

```
data Square = X | O | Empty
    deriving (Eq)
```

).

Similarly, you can check if every element is non-empty with

```
all (/= Empty) list
```

or by defining your own function `isFull :: Square -> Bool` and using `all isFull list`.

You can extract a column from a list by mapping a list index operator over it.

```
column n xss = map (!! n) xss
```

Another way, which is arguably more elegant, is to [`transpose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose) it and then look at the rows.

Comment: Thank you, but what if I need to check if the 1 dimensional list is full in general??

 So say it is [X,X,O], and the player tries to play X or O in it (anywhere, or lets just say the tail of the list or head to make it simple), then how does one error check and prevent players from playing in these full lists?

The solution above only checks for homogeneous type lists, which would help me check for win conditions though haha.